# When using body as the wrapper instead of a div, content is moved eight pixels to the left

Tags: html, css

When using body as the wrapper, instead of a div, content is moved eight pixels (on a 1920×1080 display) to the left when the content is so long that some of it is below the fold. The following two code snippets will show this difference. Note though that the difference only shows when you run the code snippet in “Full page”.

What follows is the example code for a) body as the wrapper and b) div as the wrapper:

a) Code for body as the wrapper:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 864px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<body class="wrapper">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </h1>
</body>
```

b) Code for div as the wrapper:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 864px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `width: 100vw` on the body causes it to overflow under the scrollbar. Use `width: 100%` instead.

Comment: That fixes the eight pixels. Why though is there a difference between the div and the body solution when using `width: 100vw`? I would love a detailed explanation for that. :)